# IIS7 Isapi and Cgi are disabled but site still running ( after restart)?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an IIS7 with asp.net on it.

I wanted to test the impact of `Isapi and Cgi` .

[image]

However , When I "not allowed" them all + restarted the iis - it still work !

ie : my site **still** can run !

How is that  , and what can i do those CGI's+Ispai's to take affect ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ISPI and CGI Restrictions" setting is only used when ASP.NET is running under the Classic managed pipeline mode (per-pool setting). When running in Integrated mode, it does not use ISAPI extensions.

You can disable ASP.NET in Handler Mappings by (un)setting the feature permissions.